# Is it possible in VueJS to give component prop more than one type and more than one default value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I know I can give any prop its expected type and default value like this:

```
export default {
            name: "myComponent",
            props: {
                myProp: { type: String, default: 'any text' }
           }
    }
```

And I so in documentation I can give 2 types as array like this:

```
export default {
        name: "myComponent",
        props: {
            myProp: [String, Array]
            }
}
```

BUT I would expect I can also give any of these types a default value also (this is not working): Is it possible?

```
export default {
        name: "myComponent",
        props: {
          myProp: **[{type: String, default: ''}, {type: Array, default: []} ]** 
       }
}
```

Comment: How **exactly** would you expect this to actually work?

Comment: if prop is a string it may be empty, if it got array, it will be empty array.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: No, I mean how can you have multiple "default" values? What would this look like in the parent template? Keep in mind, a `default` only applies when a value is not supplied

Comment: The component can get one of them, but it is a list of options. In my example myProp can be a string or array

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. Can you show an example of what this would look like from the parent component template, eg `<my-component ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's **impossible**, for example if you have

```
export default {
    name: "myComponent",
    props: {
      myProp: [
        {type: String, default: ''}, 
        {type: Array, default: []}
      ] 
   }
}
```

then when you write your component without passing `myProp`:

```
<my-component />
```

Then `my-component` doesn't know it should take value from default `String` or default `Array` definition.

Comment: From vue docs: you can do this -
propB: [String, Number], meaning it takes string OR number
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html
What they don't mention is what will be the default value if user set string or sets number

Comment: @AngularOne I really don't think you get it. The prop types are used for validation. If the user sets **anything**, as long as it passes that validation, that value will be used and the `default` won't be invoked at all

Comment: @ittus FYI, you need to use a `default` function to set an array or object. Not that it matters here really

Comment: @AngularOne: You can write `propB: [String, Number]`, but here you don't pass `propB` to component. Vue doesn't know it's `String` or `Number` to process.